# Show data of current month in single row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I've got a table in Excel 2013 with several data of all the year group by month (each month has his own row), and I'd like to have a single row that shows the date of the current month.
Any idea how can I implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `month(now())` to get the current month, format so that it matches the way your month labels are stored and then use `vlookup` to display the data (one vlookup per each data column)